# OpenShift 3.11 Hawkular and prometheus. When is used each one?

Tags: openshift

I'm studding OpenShift 3.11 and I see you can install Hawkular and prometheus, both at the same time.

My thoughts are that both "are the same" so I'm trying to understand in which cases or for what features are used each one.

In the documenation Prometheus/Grafana appears under "Configuring Cluster Monitoring" and Hawkular appears under "Configuring Cluster Metrics", but in the documentation about "Prometheus Cluster Monitoring" (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html#prometheus-cluster-monitoring) the metrics are collected directly from "kube-state-metrics" and "node-exporter" componentes so it doesn't seem hawkular is needed for metrics.

So why, when of for what features/uses cases is needed each one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both components are different use cases as follows.

- `Cluster Metrics`: To provide monitoring services for the end users

  - e.g.> CPU, Memory, Network metrics graph on Web console to monitor by users.
- `Prometheus Cluster Monitoring`: To provide monitoring services across cluster for cluster administrators.

  - e.g.> Monitoring resources about all node hosts and projects on the Cluster.

`Cluster Metrics` does not provide aggregated monitoring metrics across cluster, so the metrics are providing about each project level.
But Prometheus Cluster Monitoring is always providing all metrics on the cluster and it's required `cluster-admin` role.

Comment: Do you know if this is the same in 4.0? Thank you.

Comment: Cluster metrics feature is merged to Prometheus Cluster monitoring in future, refer [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/release_notes/ocp_3_11_release_notes.html#ocp-311-major-changes-in-40) for Major Changes Coming in Version 4.0 section.